# tensorflow, tensorflow-quantum, grpcio dependency conflicts

Tags: tensorflow, installation, pip, tensorflow-quantum, grpcio

I installed `tensorflow-quantum` and got the following error:

`tensorflow-quantum 0.5.0 requires grpcio==1.30.0, but you have grpcio 1.32.0 which is incompatible.`

So, I installed `grpcio 1.30.0`, but then got the following error:

`tensorflow 2.4.1 requires grpcio~=1.32.0, but you have grpcio 1.30.0 which is incompatible.`

It seems these dependency conflicts are cyclic. What should I do?

Comment: https://github.com/tensorflow/quantum/issues/572

Comment: Try a previous version: `pip install -U "tensorflow-quantum<0.5"`